# Скрытое видео

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="video_block">
    <img src="pictures/video.jpg">
    <time class="date">25 июня 2012</time>
    <h2>Lorem Lorem
    </h2>
    <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
    </p>
    <span>
        <iframeq allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="388" src="#" width="690"></iframeq>
    </span>
</div>
```

-

```
span {
    display: none;
}
```

Видео скрыто, как можно сделать, чтобы при клике на картинку выезжало видео, а картинка пряталась? А еще если на странице только 3 блока с видео (`<div class="video_block">`), то чтобы видео было показано?

Спасибо за помощь.

[Кодить можно здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/Hancock_888/89Hvw/)

Comment: @Hancock_888, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: так и делаю, не всегда срабатывает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.video_block img').click(function(){
    $(this).hide().parent().find('span').show();
});
```

Если надо, можете прицепить сюда анимацию.